# PouchDB is not defined

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am trying to instantiate PouchDB in a javascript file. I am importing it with below code :

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.type = 'text/javascript';
imported.src = 'pouchdb-6.1.2.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

Inside my custom function I am instantiating it as :

```
var db = new PouchDB('mydb');
```

This, however, is throwing an error - 'Uncaught ReferenceError: PouchDB is not defined'. Please Help

Comment: Can I ask, what forces you to import PouchDB in javascript like you are trying to do and not straight in the html?

Comment: At what point are you loading pouchdb and where are you trying to use it? My guess is that 1. You create your new script element. It goes to the end of <head> 2. You try to use it in another script before you reach your new script 3. Browser reaches the new element but it's too late.

Comment: I am using it in siebel.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this to see if it works:

```
imported.src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/pouchdb/6.2.0/pouchdb.min.js'
```

Also, you can try to add the script tag inside HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/pouchdb/6.2.0/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest PouchDb minified here: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/6.2.0/pouchdb-6.2.0.min.js

Put it in your js or scripts folder and the list it in your index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pouchdb-6.2.0.min.js"></script>
```